# reduce number of items in a frequency vector python

Tags: python, data-mining, pca

I am trying to perform dimensionality reduction in python. I have text along with their frequency count. I want to reduce the number of texts by performing dimensionality reduction on it. For example if I have a file with text and their frequency how can i reduce the number of items in python?

Comment: Identify the source of variance in your data, remove the rest. In a bag-of-words model, one way to remove redundant data while preserving variance would be to remove globally common words ('a', 'the' 'is' etc). Only keep words that are specific to the text.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways of reducing dimensionality.

Without being formal about your requirements it's hard to recommend (plus, please see the literature about this question first).

There are many cases where you can simply delete dimensions at random. E.g. minhash works this way to find near duplicate documents.